# Is there a way to instruct XCode to format a storyboard XML as one attribute per line?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

For example, a ViewController created with storyboard may look like this:

```
<viewController storyboardIdentifier="tutorial-content" title="tutorial-content" useStoryboardIdentifierAsRestorationIdentifier="YES" id="sPG-L0-gCd" userLabel="tutorial-content" customClass="TutorialContentViewController" customModule="foo" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

Which makes diff really hard to read. What I want is this:

```
<viewController 
    storyboardIdentifier="tutorial-content"
    title="tutorial-content" 
    useStoryboardIdentifierAsRestorationIdentifier="YES" 
    id="sPG-L0-gCd"
    userLabel="tutorial-content"
    customClass="TutorialContentViewController"
    customModule="foo"
    customModuleProvider="target"
    sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

Is there a way to customize storyboard file formatting like this?

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? What are you trying to accomplish by viewing the raw XML?

Comment: @JefferyThomas Our team use BitBucket, and require passing code review before a pull request can be merged. That's when we'll see a diff of the raw XML of a storyboard. It greatly helps the readability if XCode can format it one attribute per line. We can see which attributes are changed easily that way.